# PHP Sleep Is Breaking Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sleep

I have this following code:

```
<?php
$participants_db = "test_test_test_test_test_test_Sticky_Sticky_Sticky_Sticky_";
$participants = array_unique(explode("_", $participants_db));
 foreach($participants as $user)
        {
            echo $user . '\n';
            sleep(10);
        }
?>
```

I spent hours debugging this script, it actually get each username and send email to each one,
the thing is it was sending emails for each user but $user didn't change... Im wondering **Why** Sleep Break the Foreach and **How** to fix this..
http://3v4l.org/b048m

**UPDATE**
here's the Full Code:

```
foreach($participants as $user)
        {
            if($user == '')
            {
                //echo 'broken';
                break 1;
            }
            //get each user's email address
            $sql3 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
            $sql3->execute(array($user));
            while($a = $sql3->fetch())
            {
                $email = $a['email'];
                $username = $a['username'];
            }
            $message = str_replace("{USERNAME}", $username.'_'.$user, $message);
            sendemail($email, $cc, $from, $subject, $message, $filename, $filepath);
            //sleep(10);
}
```

the array (participants) contains usernames , each user has different email address.
this script gets executed by a cron job. after the execution it sent emails to 2 emails (for example), and it's saying Hello **Test_test** to Both **Emails** That have Different **Usernames**
Im just wondering, how did it get the email and the username still the same???

Comment: what do you mean break? on your case `sleep` only delays for 10 seconds after echoing `$user`

Comment: When I run the example you've provided I get the expected output. What do you see and what do you expect to see?

Comment: @Jim I expect to see 'Test\nSticky\n\' but I only see 'Test\n'

Comment: Please be aware that your script runs more then 20 seconds. The default execution time in PHP is 30 seconds. Probably it's lower on your installation of PHP. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` right after `<?php` to get errors about aborted scripts.

Comment: Ill Update the full code in few mins.. I dont think the execution time is the problem.. more like php is broken

Comment: Code Updated, This is so messed up!

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER PHP exception time doesn't take into account sleep() time or query time.

Comment: @blue112 Under Linux yes but not for Windows.

Comment: it's a Linux Machine, I still wondering this script aint working normally. Php is messed up!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `str_replace` 
it replaced the {USERNAME} with a username, then after the exection $message doesn't contain {USERNAME} Which caused the main problem of it...